# How can I get IIS version installed on a server using WMI code

Tags: iis, server, wmi

I have 2012 windows server with IIS 8 installed. I need WMI code which can help me find server versions. I have read few articles which says, I can find IIS version under root\WebAdministration namespace but, I need to know the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to readout the IIS-Version. Use the WMI Code Win32_Product for that. An example to read it from IIS Express on my computer:

```
 SELECT Version FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name='IIS 10.0 Express'
```

If you want to try this query, you can execute it with powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT Version FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name='IIS 10.0 Express'"
```

Hope I understood your question correctly. If not let me know.

Comment: Hi Presi, thank you for your response. When I execute above query with Powershell I do not get any output.  I need to know namespace/class/property name which can give me IIS version installed on server. Version for IIS installed on server may not specifically be 10. It can be 7,7.5, 8 or greater. 
For instance for iis 6 and below we have namespace MicrosoftIISv2 and class which we use is IIsWebInfo which gives Major, Minor and Install info

Comment: @Nikhilesh Maybe this query helps you:        "SELECT Version FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name  LIKE 'IIS%'" With this you not have to know the version when you execute it.